# How to pass arguments from an Array#sample! method to Array#sample

Tags: ruby

I am monkey patching the `Array` class to add an `Array#sample!` method:

- `Array#sample!` should be a destructive version of
  `Array#sample` that removes the returned elements from the array.
- `Array#sample!` should take the same arguments as `Array#sample`.

However, I fail at passing the arguments correctly. Here is what I am trying:

```
class Array
  def sample!(n = nil, **args)
    if n
      self.sample(n, args).map { |e| self.delete(e) }
    else
      self.delete(self.sample(args))
    end
  end
end

a = (1..10).to_a

p a.sample
p a.sample(4)
p a.sample(random: Random.new(1))
p a.sample(4, random: Random.new(1))

p a.sample!
p a.sample!(4)
p a.sample!(random: Random.new(1))
p a.sample!(4, random: Random.new(1))
```

And it fails with an `no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer` message :o(

Comment: What is your question? Do you expect us to write the method for you?

Comment: I don't know how this question could be more clear or focused. I've voted to reopen. @spickermann, isn't the question clear from the title?

Comment: maasha, it is not possible because you cannot duplicate the form of [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) that takes no arguments. For example, `[1,2,3].sample #=> 2`, so you are asking to replace an array (`self`) with an object that is not an array (an integer), which is not permitted.

Comment: When `sample!` takes one or two arguments, the first being an integer, you could use [Array#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-replace): `def sample!(*args); replace(sample(*args)); end` (`replace(sample(*args))` is the same as `self.replace(self.sample(*args)`, as `self` is the default receiver).

Comment: Cary, alas, it stills give a TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the argument passing. You can either do it like this: (the splat (`*`) effectively omits the positional argument if `n` is `nil`)

```
class Array
  def my_sample(n = nil, **kwargs)
    sample(*n, **kwargs)
  end
end

[1, 2, 3].my_sample #=> 3
[1, 2, 3].my_sample(2) #=> [1, 3]
[1, 2, 3].my_sample(random: Random.new(1)) #=> 2
[1, 2, 3].my_sample(2, random: Random.new(1)) #=> [2, 3]
```

Or you could use a conditional:

```
class Array
  def my_sample(n = nil, **kwargs)
    if n
      sample(n, **kwargs)
    else
      sample(**kwargs)
    end
  end
end
```

---

Implementing a `sample!` method that works just like `sample` but which also removes those element(s) might be a little more complex than your approach.

Since arrays can contain the same element multiple times, you have to take special care to remove the correct ones. (you cant just remove all duplicates, neither an arbitrary one)

Something like this would probably work:

```
class Array
  def sample!(n = nil, **kwargs)
    indices = (0...size).to_a
    if n
      samples = indices.sample(n, **kwargs)
      remaining = indices - samples
      return_value = values_at(*samples)
    else
      sample = indices.sample(**kwargs)
      remaining = indices - [sample]
      return_value = at(sample)
    end
    replace(values_at(*remaining))
    return_value
  end
end
```

Here, I'm creating an array of *indices* (which are guaranteed to be unique) and sample from that array. I then determine the remaining indices (which is simply the difference), set the return value and adjust the array content.

You could unify both code paths but that makes the code a little harder to read.

Comment: Stefan, great, thanks! Good catch on handling duplicates! Now, how to get this method included in Ruby core? :o)

Comment: Has already been proposed: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5584 (and was rejected)

Comment: Gawd :o) `%w[reject reject reject].sample!`